# Cart items in customer_login observer

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, login

I am trying to get contents in login observer, however I always get null. What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class CustomerLoginAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $checkoutSession;
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession, \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $quoteItemsAll = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        echo count($quoteItemsAll);
    }

}
```

Comment: @sv3n what the hell did you edit here? My question title doesnt make any sense now!

Comment: I've just added some tags, the title was changed by someone else. Changed it back ... https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/188052/revisions

Comment: This is most likely related to the full page cache.... Does it work if you turn it off?

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, it's working fine in my system. Make sure you use right observer event.

Also, add `<sequence>` to load your module after checkout module in **module.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Test/Test/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerLoginAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Test/Test/Observer/CustomerLoginAfter.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

class CustomerLoginAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(Session $session) {
        $this->_session = $session;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
         $items = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllItems();

         foreach ($items as $item) {
            print_r($item->getItemId());    
         }
         exit;
    }
}
```

**Note: Make sure you have products in cart before login.**

Now flush cache and try.